# Navigator Add options of jqgrid using struts2-jquery tag?

Tags: java, jquery, jqgrid, struts2, struts

I am using jqgrid (struts2-jquery tag).what are the default parameters for Navigator Add Options in sjg:grid tags

Some options i found were

```
navigatorAddOptions="{height:250,width:500,reloadAfterSubmit:true,afterSubmit:serverErrorCheck,addCaption:'Add Holiday',beforeSubmit:valSetup,beforeSubmitForm:callMe,closeAfterAdd:true}"
```

what are the other options in Navigator Add ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [Jquery Grid wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator) will be helpful.